# Calculate a delta from list

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, xquery

I have this list:

- ADD X
- ADD Y
- REMOVE Z
- ADD X
- NO ACTION Y

I need of this results:

- ADD X
- NO ACTION Y
- REMOVE Z

The rules to calculate the delta are these:
I have 3 action (ADD, REMOVE, NO ACTION)

1. ANY ACTION * NO ACTION = NO ACTION
2. ADD * REMOVE or REMOVE * ADD = NO ACTION
3. SAME ACTION * SAME ACTION = SAME ACTION

The problem is that I implement this with a functional language (XQuery). I found a logic, based on fn:distinct-values. But the last rule (3) is unsatisfied.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is the input list to be processed sequentially?

Comment: No. The list came from an xml.

Comment: Sorry, but you did not understand what I was asking.  The result seems to be dependent on the order of the input elements.

Comment: Oh, sorry .. No.. the result depends on the order .. The ordering of
lists, in this case, not relevant. You immagine that this is an xml that represents an order. In the order line you found a name of service (Z,X,Y,etc..) and the action (ADD, REMOVE, NO ACTION). The algorithm made this: If the in the order are present services with same name and different actions, the final order contains only one service name with the action specified by the rules (This is needed, if inside an order there are opposite action for the same service).

Comment: I think you need to give more examples that illustrate the application of every rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way. I hope that this is good.

These are my first experiments with XQuery and I need to remeber what I have under my fingers and what possibilities this language offer.

My problem is data that came in. And I decide to transformate the information in a structure  that can I easily manipulate.

A golden brick to solve this is this example about grouping data :

```
for $d in distinct-values(doc("order.xml")//item/@dept)
let $items := doc("order.xml")//item[@dept = $d]
order by $d
return <department code="{$d}">{
     for $i in $items
     order by $i/@num
     return $i
   }</department>
```

After this I used this algorithm:
0. If the count of action == 1 -> take first action
1. else If exist almost ONE - NO ACTION -> NO ACTION (RULE 1)
2. else If exist ADD and REMOVE in same list -> NO ACTION  (RULE 2)
3. else take the first action (equal actions)

For this I borrowed a function from functx library:

```
declare function local:is-value-in-sequence( $value as xs:anyAtomicType? ,$seq as      xs:anyAtomicType* )  as xs:boolean {
 $value = $seq
 };
```

Simple but effective.

Thanks a lot for all!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what XQuery processor you are using, but if it has hashmaps, you can do it this way (tested in MarkLogic Server):

```
let $seq := ("ADD X", "ADD Y", "REMOVE Z", "ADD X", "NO-ACTION Y")
let $map := map:map()
let $_ :=
  for $s in $seq 
  let $parts := fn:tokenize($s, " ")
  let $service := $parts[2]
  let $action := $parts[1]
  let $current-action := map:get($map, $service)
  return
    if ("NO-ACTION" = ($action, $current-action)) then
      map:put($map, $service, "NO-ACTION") (: rule 1 :)
    else if ("REMOVE" = ($action, $current-action)) then
      map:put($map, $service, "REMOVE") (: rule 2 :)
    else
      map:put($map, $service, $action) (: actions are the same -- rule 3 :)
for $service in map:keys($map)
return fn:concat(map:get($map, $service), " ", $service)
```

Returns

```
ADD X 
REMOVE Z 
NO-ACTION Y
```

Note that I made a simplifying assumption and changed "NO ACTION" to "NO-ACTION" to make the parsing simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately Saxon-EE 9.2.0.3